# load(), scrollTop()

Tags: javascript

функцией load() я обновляю div , но почему-то перестает работать скрипт scrollTop которым я опускаю скролл этого дива вниз.

В head добавил скрипт:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function f(){ 
        $("#mucho").load("room.php #masaga2");
    }, 5000);)
</scripte>
```

в теле div id="masaga2"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#masaga2').scrollTop(100000);
    }); 
</script>
```

Вот этот скрипт в теле div="masaga2" не раотает, а при обновлении всей страницы работает.

Comment: если это код из исходной страницы, там очень странный закрывающий тег `</scriptE>`..

Comment: =)) не дело не в этом. Скрипт работает нормально, но скролл внизу только после обновления всей страницы а при обновлении div поднимается вверх

Comment: зачем делать `scrollTop` на 100.000 точек?

Comment: var fini = document.getElementById("masaga2");
           fini.scrollTop=fini.scrollHeight; я и так делал тоже, пробовал по разному. скрип не погружается

Comment: тогда залей рабочий код на jsfiddle.net, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так а что ты хочешь:  $(document).ready() срабатывает после загрузки документа, а если хочешь, чтобы срабатывала после загрузки через load, то как-то так -

```
 $("#mucho").load("room.php #masaga2", function() {
     $('#masaga2').scrollTop(100000);//Срабатывает по окончании загрузки через load()
 });
```

Comment: УРА!!!!!! заработало!!!!! Спасибо пацаны, я вас люблю!)))))